# a very high client wait time in impala profile when querying from ssh

Tags: cloudera, impala

Im Currently accessing Impala from the shell and only have options to ssh, run the query, pipe the result to a tt file, do some regex and convert it into a CSV. I do not have access to any GUIs.

While running through ssh, I noticed a very high client fetch wait timer.. would love some help understanding what might be causing this and how I can fix it?

> ```
> Query Timeline: 17m32s
>    - Query submitted: 46.142us (46.142us)
>    - Planning finished: 89.096ms (89.050ms)
>    - Submit for admission: 89.929ms (832.271us)
>    - Completed admission: 90.000ms (71.224us)
>    - Ready to start on 19 backends: 90.388ms (387.968us)
>    - All 19 execution backends (29 fragment instances) started: 100.725ms (10.337ms)
>    - Rows available: 3s024ms (2s923ms)
>    - First row fetched: 3s056ms (32.067ms)
>    - Last row fetched: 17m32s (17m29s)
>    - Released admission control resources: 17m32s (31.955ms)
>    - Unregister query: 17m32s (485.585ms)
>  - ComputeScanRangeAssignmentTimer: 157.967us   ImpalaServer:
>  **- ClientFetchWaitTimer: 17m8s**
>  - RowMaterializationTimer: 20s696ms
> ```

Comment: check them out `  - First row fetched: 3s056ms (32.067ms)
   - Last row fetched: 17m32s (17m29s)`, you may have lot of data which means it will take time to fetch all the data. 17min is spent doing only fetching data\

Comment: thank you koushik ! i appologise for my noob question ! what you said makes a lot of sense !

Comment: :) another problem solved, another day! Have a nice day ahead...